# Display product attribute value from order item in Woocommerce email subject

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

In woocommerce, I'm trying to get a specific product attribute value and display it in the subject line for admin new order email notification.

I found the following code, but I have a poor knowledges to make it work:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);
function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    global $product;       
    {
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
        $subject = sprintf( '[%s] New customer order (# %s) from %s %s',
                               $blogname, $order->id,
                               $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name );
    } 
    return $subject;
}
```

I tried also this one *(where the `xxxxx` is slug of my attribute)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);
function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    global $product;       
    {  
        $pa_xxxxx_value = get_order_meta($order->id, 'pa_xxxxx', true);
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
        $subject = sprintf( '[%s] [%s] New customer order (# %s) from %s %s',
                              $pa_xxxxx_value, $blogname, $order->id,
                              $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name );
    } 
    return $subject;
}
```

But it is not working eitheir.

How can I get and display a specific product attribute value from order item in Woocommerce email subject?

Comment: When you say it's not working, are you getting the modified subject line but just with your value missing, i.e. it starts "[] [blogname] New customer order"? Or is it not updating the subject line at all, or some other error?

Comment: I guess your problem is `get_order_meta`; I can't see that in the WooCommerce source, so I think that should be [`$order->get_meta('pa_xxxxx_value', true)`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_meta). But I'm not an expert here. It also looks like you can return `{site_name}` in your subject line and the WC_Email class will fill in the blog name for you: you don't need to find that and substitute it yourself. And you possibly want to use accessors for the order properties too, e.g. `$order->get_billing_first_name()`.

Comment: Dear Rup, yes I'm getting modified subject, but attribute is missing []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders can have many items, and there is some errors in your code since Woocommerce 3.

The code below will search through order items for a specific product attribute (taxonomy) and if it's found, it will display a new custom subject with this product attribute term name value:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);
function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    // HERE define the product attribute taxonomy (start always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_color'; //

    // Loop through order items searching for the product attribute defined taxonomy
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        // If product attribute is found
        if( $item->get_meta($taxonomy) ){
            // Custom new subject including the product attribute term name
            $subject = sprintf( '[%s] [%s] New customer order (# %s) from %s %s',
                get_term_by('slug', $item->get_meta($taxonomy), $taxonomy )->name, // Term name
                wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES),
                $order->get_id(),
                $order->get_billing_first_name(),
                $order->get_billing_last_name()
            );
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.